# why compiler give me error when i assign char variable to int variable in global scope?

Tags: c, variables, global

I have an error

> initializer element is not constant

when I initialize variable in global scope 
this is my wrong code

```
char x = 65 ;
int c =  x ;
int main(void) {

    printf("%d",c); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but when i
initialize int variable inside main functions it works correctly

```
char x = 65 ;
int main(void) {
    int c =  x ;
    printf("%d",c); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initializers for global variables must be a compile time constant.  The value of another variable (even a `const` variable) is *not* a compile time constant.

A numeric constant (or an expression consisting only of numeric constants) is a compile time constant.